# Ionic Push Notification Example giving 403 forbidden error

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a simple push notification app from [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push) as code pasting as it is(When I say as it. I changed the token Id and all those parameter)this was giving 400 Bad Request(I feel probably because the Authorization field was missing from the headers). So started looking and found out they also have an example [here](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-api-examples#send-a-notification-to-a-list-of-tokens). But again I got 403 forbidden error. Now on their site, they have proved error code which says.

> 403
>
> Invalid or missing registration. Check that the request contains a
>   registration token (in the registration_id in a plain text message, or
>   in the to or registration_ids field in JSON).

So I did and found no mistake. 
Here is the code.

```
  var privateKey = 'AIzaSyBeU6owUdakHAmQPEK0GcX1uv8K0H1I8fA'; //the key I got from google. I will change it in an hour
                var tokens = ['fslJofRFUOk:APA91bFYJnOufZGo4xSwJsDn3pIZEKl_ZZWdLHn3xY3HQeIV9g3MFx2yeYVvMIGq7Lr4ZMSM2yTxjGytzUt3AiM8xPPKBHuF5zX5Liu7wfo6lSgODukRtUbVLaVwF_RhvYrh3kr1uyjV']; //
                var appId = '490668543641';

                // Encode your key
                var auth = btoa(privateKey + ":");
                console.log(auth);
                // Build the request object
                var req = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-Ionic-Application-Id': 490668543641,
                        'Authorization': 'basic ' + auth
                    },
                    data: {
                        "tokens": tokens,
                        "notification": {
                            "alert": "Hello World!",
                        "android": {
                            "collapseKey": "foo",
                            "delayWhileIdle": true,
                            "timeToLive": 300,
                            "payload": {
                                "key1": "value",
                                "key2": "value"
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                    };

                    // Make the API call
                    $http(req).success(function(resp) {
                        // Handle success
                        console.log("Ionic Push: Push success!");
                    }).error(function(error) {
                        // Handle error 
                        console.log("Ionic Push: Push error...");
                    });
```

I am still getting 403 Forbidden Error. What is the mistake here? 
Doubt : Is the private key is same as we got from google?

Comment: Same problem here, have you resolved yours? :)

Comment: I couldn't achieve it via curl. But I was successful in doing it via phone.